# Divide array into equal sized subarrays

Tags: arrays, math

we are given an array of size n (n is even), we have to divide it into two equal-sized subarrays array1 and array2, sized n/2 each such that product of all the numbers of array1 equals to the product of all the numbers in array2.

Given array:

```
arr = [2, 4, 5, 12, 15, 18]
```

solution:

```
array2 = [4, 5, 18]
array1 = [2, 12, 15]
```

Explanation:

product of all elements in array1 is 360
product of all elements in array2 is 360.

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate programming language and share what you have tried so far, explaining why it doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be soved using dynamic programming. You need to get subset of size `n/2` with product equal to `p = sqrt(overall_product)`. Note that there is no solution when `overall_product` is not exact square.

Recursion might look like

```
solution(p, n/2, arr) = choose valid solution from 
             solution(p / arr[i], n/2-1, arr without arr[i])
return true for arguments (1,0,...)
```

use memoization or table to solve problem with merely large n values.